# GWT: "unrecognized calling format": What does it mean?

Tags: gwt, interop

```
public void query(String sql, QueryResult queryResult) {
    q = queryResult;
    realQuery(sql, conString);
}

public static native void realQuery(String sql, String conString) /*-{
    $wnd.pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {
        client.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            console.log(result.rows);
            var code = "@db.tud.bp.werkstatt.client.PgClient::result(Ljava/lang/String;)(" + '"' + JSON.stringify(result.rows).replace('"','\\"') + '"' + ");";
            console.log(code);
            eval(code);
        });
    });
}-*/;
```

I get this error:

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (Error) 
@de.tud.bp.werkstatt.client.PgClient::realQuery(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)
([string: 'SELECT age FROM person WHERE name='Ayeb'', string: '/rest/query']): 
  unrecognized calling format
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
```

What does "unrecognized calling format" mean, and why do I not get any Google results when searching for it?

I suspect that I am calling the JSNI function in a wrong way in line 3. But I am AFAIK following all rules specified in the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI#writing).

**EDIT**:

This works:

```
public static native void realQuery(JavaScriptObject parsed) /*-{
    var sql = parsed[0];
    var conString = parsed[1];
    $wnd.pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {
    });
}-*/;
```

This doesn't:

```
public static native void realQuery(JavaScriptObject parsed) /*-{
    var sql = parsed[0];
    var conString = parsed[1];
    $wnd.pg.connect(conString, function(err, client) {
        client.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            console.log(result.rows);
        });
    });
}-*/;
```

Comment: Is your `result` method a static one? Does it receive only one String as argument? If so, your `" + '"' + JSON.stringify(result.rows).replace('"','\\"') + '"' + "` may be the problem.

Comment: @GilbertoTorrezan: As far as I can see, the error is thrown just before the function call. result is declared so: `static void result(String json)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `eval` JSNI invocations into Java - that code is not real JavaScript, but is part of how JS and Java interact within GWT. The way this ends up working is that those invocations are rewritten so that they call the real JavaScript function.

Comment: What do you have without the eval? just the log statement? And what is the wrapped (i.e. inside the UmbrellaException) error? You are also apparently calling the `query` method as if it was static (no `instance.` in front of it), but it isn't static. Both that and the eval don't really make sense, and should be clarified in the question. One more, before I add the comment - you only list one of the two args in the `query` method sig in JSNI - where is the QueryResult?

Comment: by "without the eval" I meant that I just replaced it with a normal JSNI function call. Full stack trace here: https://gist.github.com/4021567 . The eval is from an earlier iteration where I wanted to make it more dynamic, but it doesn't matter right now, I just need to get the call working first.

Comment: PgClient.java: https://gist.github.com/4021581 Pg.java (QueryResult is here): https://gist.github.com/4021585

Comment: (in the source posted I tried passing a JavaScriptObject instead, but it doesn't seem to make much difference what I pass.)

Comment: The "query" in the JS code is not the "query" from the Java code.

Comment: Even with these other details, there isn't a lot I can offer. "Unrecognized calling format" doesn't appear to be a GWT exception, but something either from your browser, or that Java is complaining about. Consider compiling with style=PRETTY, and getting a JS exception. At best, you'll get a compile error telling you what part of your JSNI doesn't make sense, and if not, you can use the browser's own debugging to give the real error.